# set default root url with pelican does not work

Tags: pelican

for testing purposes I have the pelican content behind a uuid like http://mydomain/uuid

for that I changed the default publishconf.py to

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- #
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.curdir)
from pelicanconf import *

SITEURL = '0aba739a-1de6-11eb-b637-2b634940aeb7'
RELATIVE_URLS = False

FEED_ALL_ATOM = 'feeds/all.atom.xml'
CATEGORY_FEED_ATOM = 'feeds/{slug}.atom.xml'

DELETE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY = True

# Following items are often useful when publishing

#DISQUS_SITENAME = ""
#GOOGLE_ANALYTICS = ""
```

but it is not replacing all root urls. Some are just / or even /mydomain/. How can I make sure all output files are unsing a /uuid for all local reference links ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give the complete url as:

```
SITEURL = 'http://mydomain/uuid'
```

without the http:// pelican doesnt use SITEURL for some reason.

Comment: that is a  hard thing to use, could be https or http and how to test than locally ? btw it confused than lurls inks in the articles

Comment: @salwal checked again, doesn't work with latest pelican version

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found that there is a setting for that in pelicanconf.py

that puts all content in a different folder than out out therefore the root url for all links is different

```
OUTPUT_PATH = 'my_desired_sub_path'
```